# Issue loading kernel (uimage) for omap 3530 using tftp

Tags: kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot, omap

I am trying to load `uImage` and `filesystem` using `tftpboot/nfs`. However, I am having the following issue.

In my `uboot` I have following settings:

```
bootargs=mem=128M 
ip=dhcp noinitrd console=ttyS0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rw
nfsroot=192.168.x.x:/tftpboot,nolock,rsize=1024,wsize=1024
```

`serverip`, `gatewayip` and `ipaddr` are setup. I can ping target device from the host and vice versa.

I am loading `uImage` with the following:

```
setenv bootnfs 'tftp  0x80000000 uImage; bootm'
run bootnfs

$ cat /etc/exports
/tftpboot *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=0,no_root_squash)
```

In my host under `/tftpboot` I have unzipped the file system (nfs.tar.gz)

```
$ ls /tftpboot
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  linuxrc  media  mnt  nfs.tar.gz  proc
sbin  srv  sys  tmp  uImage  usr  var
```

Notice I also have `uImage` under `/tftpboot`.

I am not sure where to put uImage.

Comment: Your post is confusing, as if you don't know how to use TFTP and NFS.  *"I am trying to load uImage and filesystem using tftpboot/nfs"* -- A slash is usually read as "or", so what you wrote is *"... using tftpboot or nfs"*, and reads as if you don't know the difference between those two protocols.  IMO a root filesystem that will be mounted by NFS does not belong under `/tftpboot`.  *"I am not sure where to put uImage."* -- The correct location to store uImage depends on how the TFTP server was setup.  If the TFTP server is configured to use `/tftpboot`, then that is the answer.

Comment: No, you are not correct.  `/etc/exports` is for NFS, and has nothing to do with TFTP.  The directory for the TFTP server is specified in its config file or the inetd config file.  A TFTP directory should not even be in the `/etc/exports` file.  Likewise, an NFS rootfs does not belong in the TFTP directory.  And more questions do not belong in an answer, but should be appended to your original post by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

sawdust,
Thanks for the reply. You are right the source of the problem is my confusion with tftp and nfs. I have not tested it yet but from what I understood from your reply:

uImage goes in /tftpboot since tftp server is set up to point to /tftpboot path (indicated by /etc/exports)

```
$ cat /etc/exports
/tftpboot *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,fsid=0,no_root_squash)
```

filesystem (nfs.tar.gz) will be unzipped and go in  /tftpboot/fs but I have to modify bootargs little bit ( to point to /tftpboot/fs)

```
bootargs=mem=128M ip=dhcp noinitrd console=ttyS0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs 

rw nfsroot=192.168.x.x:/tftpboot/fs,nolock,rsize=1024,wsize=1024
```

Am I correct?

One more question on OMAP35x Mistral board, do I need to change any hardware jumper setting if booting from nfs? correctly it boots fine from NAND I am trying to change it to nfs so that I can  do some development work from host system (Linux Ubuntu14.4)?

Comment: for loading uImage i've used tftpboot..But for loading rootfs which steps you taken?Can you pls mention it?